# Weird laravel message after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, laravel-5

I've updated to Ubuntu 16.04.  Now all of my Laravel applications simply display an unformated text message:

> */ /* |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | Register The Auto Loader
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class
>   loader for | our application. We just need to utilize it!

No errors, nothing in the logs.  What happened here?

Comment: Make sure your php service is up and working !

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out Ubuntu 16 upgrades to PHP7.  This was causing an issue.  I ran

sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php

enabled the module, and PRESTO!